# C# How to convert the date that have been retrieve from DB and Where should I write?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, datetime, formatting

In this task, I am trying to write a method that filters according to the date entered by the user. But I couldn't figure out where and how to write the format changing code.

I have a DateTime object in database like this :`2022-08-09 11:42:26.3600000(y/m/d)`

When the user enters the date in the following format : `09/08/2022`, I am trying to show the data in the database in the following format : `09/08/2022 11:42` to the user. And when the user enters as `d/m/y`, the datas that matches this date will be returned as a list.

If it matches more than one data, it will return as a list.

this is my controller method:

```
[HttpGet("date/{date}")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<ActionResult<Result>> GetPartySearchHistoriesByDate([BindRequired] DateTime date)
{
  try
  {
    var items = await _mediator.Send(new GetPartySearchHistoriesByDateQuery() {Date = date});

    return Result.Ok(new
    {
      MatchCount = items.Count,
      Matches = items
    });
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
            throw new SanctionException("An error occurred while fetching record.", ex);
  }
}
```

This is Handler :

```
public async Task<IList<PartySearchHistoryVM>> Handle(GetPartySearchHistoriesByDateQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var dates = await _partySearchHistoryRepository.GetListByDateAsync(request.Date);
    return dates.Adapt<IList<PartySearchHistoryVM>>();
}
```

this is dapper method:

```
public async Task<List<PartySearchHistoryDto>> GetListByDateAsync(DateTime dateTime)
{
    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = await _dbConnection.GetUnitOfWorkAsync();
    unitOfWork.Begin();
    try
    {
        var partySearchHistories = await unitOfWork
            .Connection
            .QueryAsync<PartySearchHistoryDto>(
            @$"SELECT *
          FROM [dbo].[PartySearchHistories] WITH (NOLOCK)
          WHERE CreatedAt = @dateTime
            AND IsDeleted = 0",
            new { dateTime },
            transaction: unitOfWork.Transaction);

        return partySearchHistories.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return new List<PartySearchHistoryDto>();
    }
}
```

this code only works if you send exactly the format in the database as a parameter.

Comment: Displaying something in right way is a UI concern, your api should just return data in UTC format, and client side will format it in appropriate way.

Comment: Is `CreatedAt` in the database a datetime type? When you say it "only works if...", do you mean that it only returns results if the client does that? Is it the exact format, or the exact time? Do you need to query a day range instead?

Comment: Yes, `CreatedAt` is datetime type in the database. If I send like this : `2022-08-09 11:42:26.3600000` return the colon with this data. what I want, when the user enters as `dd/mm/yyyy`, the datas that matches this date will be returned as a list @DiplomacyNotWar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using a direct SQL query, try to do the conversion directly in it, this way:

```
"SELECT *
      FROM [dbo].[PartySearchHistories] WITH (NOLOCK)
      WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, CreatedAt, 103) = @dateTime
        AND IsDeleted = 0"
```

Comment: When I send it this way:`09-08-2022`, yes I can get the results I want. Thank you for answer. Is it correct to send it in this way in terms of format? @Anderson Constantino

Comment: @dogac, It will be conditioned to the format entered by the user, that is, it must be treated so that it always arrives in the expected format.